# Applying FoldList to its own output

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm trying to figure out a functional way to essentially apply `FoldList` (or some related function such as `Nest` or `ListCorrelate`) to its own output. By this, I mean given some initial `a` and some total length, I want to generate the following list

```
{a, f[a], f[a,f[a]], f[a,f[a],f[a,f[a]]], ...}
```

However, there is an additional complexity that as the function `f` will ultimately have some randomness involved, I don't want each new call to `f[a]` to be a new execution of the function `f`, but rather to simply call the values which have already been calculated in previous indices. In other words, I am looking for a functional way to apply the function `f` to all elements left of the current element being calculated, with scalability to large list lengths in mind.

I've managed to implement this via recursion relations, but its a bit cumbersome and can get slow for large lengths. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Roman had an excellent answer below, but I'm now looking to try and implement a more complex version of this code. I'll add a bit of a clarification of the form of `f` to hopefully make my goal clearer - this is copied from a comment below:

The function f takes two inputs, a single value f0, and a list L. It then does a slightly random calculation which relies on both f0 and all values in L, and then generates a new value f1 and a new value, e. The output of f is then the list {f1,Append[L,e]}.

A sample output of what I'm looking for, with inputs a1 and {e1}:

```
{{a1, {e1}}, f[a1, {e1}] (*={a2,{e1,e2}}*), f[a2, {e1, e2}](*={a3, 
{e1,e2,e3}*), f[a3, {e1, e2, e3}](*={a4,{e1,e2,e3,e4}*), ...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Nest[Append[#, f @@ #] &, {a}, 3]
```

> {a, f[a], f[a, f[a]], f[a, f[a], f[a, f[a]]]}

For the second part of your question I think it would be easier to define your function `f` such that the list appending is performed inside `f`: for example, a function that from a number `a` and a list of $e$-values `elist` calculates new numbers `anew` and `enew` (here symbolized by `RandomReal[]` but should really do your calculation):

```
f[a_, elist_] := Module[{anew, enew},
  anew = RandomReal[];
  enew = RandomReal[];
  {anew, Append[elist, enew]}]

NestList[Apply[f], {a0, {e0}}, 3]
```

> {{a0, {e0}}, {0.425748, {e0, 0.268434}}, {0.248881, {e0, 0.268434, 0.983386}}, {0.945438, {e0, 0.268434, 0.983386, 0.546319}}}

If you're only interested in the last member of this output, replace `NestList` with `Nest`.

Comment: This is an excellent answer - and just what I needed. I'm now trying to implement a more generalized version which can deal with two inputs, and for `f` having two outputs. I've edited my question above - any ideas on how to implement this in a similar way to your above answer?

Comment: For the second part of your question, I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you want. Could it be that the same solution works but replacing `a` with a list of two elements `{a,b}`? Something like `Nest[Append[#, f @@ #] &, {{a, b}}, 3]` generating `{{a, b}, f[{a, b}], f[{a, b}, f[{a, b}]], f[{a, b}, f[{a, b}], f[{a, b}, f[{a, b}]]]}`. You'll have to define the function `f` correspondingly, to accept a sequence of number pairs instead of a pair of number lists. Let me know if this is the right direction.

Comment: Not quite - in concrete terms, the function `f` takes two inputs, a single value `f0`, and a list `L`. It then does a slightly random calculation which relies on both `f0` and all values in `L`, and then generates a new value `f1` and a new value, `e`. The output of `f` is then the list {f1,Append[L,e]}.

Comment: Like I said, I have this implemented via memoization/recursion, and can think of pretty straightforward ways to do it via loops, but as the number of calculations will need to be in the tens of thousands, I think both loops/recursion are not quite efficient enough.

Comment: Maybe this sample output will make it clear what I'm looking for, with inputs `a1` and `{e1}`:

`{{a1, {e1}}, f[a1, {e1}] (*={a2,{e1,e2}}*), 
 f[a2, {e1, e2}](*={a3,{e1,e2,e3}*), 
 f[a3, {e1, e2, e3}](*={a4,{e1,e2,e3,e4}*), ...}`

Answer (score 1):

"*I don't want each new call to f[a] to be a new execution of the function f, but rather to simply call the values which have already been calculated in previous indices*"

It looks like [memoisation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) will accomplish this, e.g.

```
f[x_] := f[x] = x + y
y = 0.1;
NestList[f, a, 4]
```

> {a, 0.1 + a, 0.2 + a, 0.3 + a, 0.4 + a}

```
Clear[y]
NestList[f, a, 4]
```

> {a, 0.1 + a, 0.2 + a, 0.3 + a, 0.4 + a}

Without any value for `y`, `f` has called the previously calculated values.

```
f[a + 0.3]
```

> 0.4 + a

Also see `DownValues[f]`